# How to check duplicate value

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

`Table Tab1 ( Col1, Col2 )`
`Table Tab2 ( Col1, Col2 )`

I want to check in the table `Tab2` `Col2` is there any same value with the table `Tab1` in column `Col2`.

How to do that?

Comment: What database product and version or should we assume anything in the SQL specification from 92 to present?

Answer (score 5):

### Using EXISTS

```
SELECT t2.col2
  FROM TABLE2 t2
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                 FROM TABLE1 t1
                WHERE t1.col2 = t2.col2)
```

### Using IN

```
SELECT t2.col2
  FROM TABLE2 t2
 WHERE t2.col2 IN (SELECT t1.col2
                     FROM TABLE1 t1)
```

### Using JOIN:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.col2
  FROM TABLE2 t2
  JOIN TABLE1 t1 ON t1.col2 = t2.col2
```

Comment: I have given my code below where I have used your code but it does not work

Comment: ALTER trigger [sub_contracting_order]        
on        
[dbo].[pur_gi_header]        
for insert        
as
DECLARE @Test nVarchar(100);
BEGIN   
 IF  EXISTS(select 'X' from inserted a where a.po_category = 'SER' AND a.no_of_item = '0' )
     BEGIN     
      EXEC pur_msg_rtr '02999200052', 'For Service Orders, Machine No is Mandatory' , 'I'   
     END

Comment: IF  EXISTS(SELECT t2.no_of_item from pur_gi_header t2 WHERE  t2.no_of_item IN (SELECT t1.no_of_item from inserted t1))  
     BEGIN     
      EXEC pur_msg_rtr '02999200052', '1 No. already exist, Machine No is Mandatory' , 'I'

Comment: How to use EXISTS in t2.col2 ?

Comment: @user724817 Update your question instead of posting code in comments